# onResume not working for android launchMode standard in Worklight project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 5.0.5
Android - 4.1

I have been working to merge a native and hybrid code base into a single worklight application.  As part of that I have updated my launcher activity launchMode to 'standard' so that when the app is resumed it restores to either the correct webview or to another activity based on last activity the user was viewing.  (worklight default projects are set to 'singleTask')

This configuration works fine when building from eclipse directly onto he device.  When I create a signed APK copy to the device and install I get different behavior for the resume lifecycle.  Here are the steps that create the error

1. Start App
2. Change the state of the app
3. Press Home button
4. Open application folder
5. Click app icon
   RESULT - App runs onCreate rather than onResume

What is strange is that if I do a long press on home, and choose my app from recently used it resumes as normal.  (why would they be different?)

I recently upgraded to 5.0.5 and have only now noticed the issue. Perhaps its related to the new phonegap version?

The issue is easy to recreate with a new Worklight project.

1. Use the new project wizard with no framework.
2. Modify your android activity

   ```
   activity android:name=".SimpleWorklight"
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
             android:launchMode="standard"
   ```
3. Update the markup so that you can change its state to prove an onCreate, vs on onResume

   ```
   <input type="submit" onclick="buttonClick()">
   <span id=label>SimpleWorklight</span>
   ```

   var counter=1;
       function buttonClick(){
           document.getElementById("label").innerText="Clicked"+counter;
           counter=counter+1; 
       }

It is reasonably similar to this
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/UjWcsFMe6ik

UPDATE - I attempted the same test and got the same result running with 5.0.2.407-developer-edition
Aaron Allsbrook

Comment: I have now tried this without using worklight.... Building android projects with cordova 1.5 and cordova 2.2 I still see a failure to call onResume when clicking the app icon

Comment: This appears to be an issue purely with android and signed builds http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373 ... testing workarounds now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue, it appears to be a possible bug in android (or maybe just the way android behaves)  When you launch from the app icon it basically always starts a new activity on top of the existing one if it was there already.  There are a couple of possible solutions mentioned here.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373

I first tried the simpliest approach of adding to the onCreate method

```
     if (!isTaskRoot()) {
         finish();
         return;
     }
```

but this returned NPEs back from the cordovawebview library.  Rather than trying to debug through Worklight and into Cordova I tried the solution found here https://github.com/cleverua/android_startup_activity

Where you create a startup android activity that will look at all the running tasks.  If it finds the task running it will simply close the new activity and fall back to the running one.  If it doesnt find the task running it will create the new intent and transition over.